# Is there a way to stop Airplay programmatically and reset it back to iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, jwplayer, airplay

My iOS App has 2 types of video players, one for Livestream and other for VOD. And i have not implemented Airplay on Livestream. When i start Airplay to my Apple Tv on VOD and switch back to Livestream(another view controller)it automatically switches back to Airplay.

I want to disable airplay for my Livestream at any case, how can i do it? 
Is there a way to get a shared airplay session and remove it or switch it back to iPhone?

Note: i use JWPlayer for Livestream

I have created an AVPlayer within livestream controller and tried below, it does not work

```
// create a player
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:"YOUR URL"];
player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = NO;
player.allowsExternalPlayback = NO;
```

Comment: Hi, did you already found a solution on this? Got the same problem.